# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms' when trying to docker-compose

Tags: python, docker

I am just starting out to play with Dockers. I have read up on Dockers and have watched a few tutorial videos. I am trying to create a simple form using Python that I will build and use Docker to display on my localhost. I am using ***flask*** and ***wtforms***. I have pip installed flask, flask_wtf, and wtforms but when I try to build using `sudo docker-compose up`, I keep getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms'`. I have read through many other similar questions on here, but none of the solutions works for me. I have copied the three files I am using below:

**-- api.py --**

```
# docker test 

from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField

app= Flask(__name__)
api= Api(app)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '7d441f27d441f27567d441f2b6176a'
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])

class UserForm(Form):
    salutation= TextField('Salutation:', validators= [validators.required()])
    first_name= TextField('First Name:', validators= [validators.required()])
    last_name= TextField('Last Name:', validators= [validators.required()])

def welcome():
    form = UserForm(request.form)
    print(form.errors)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        salutation=request.form['salutation']
        first_name=request.form['first_name']
        last_name=request.form['last_name']
        print(salutation)
        print(first_name)
        print(last_name)

        if form.validate():
            flash('Welcome' + salutation + last_name)
        else:
            flash('Please fill in the required fields.')

api.add_resource(UserForm, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

**-- requirements.txt --**

```
Flask==0.12
flask-restful==0.3.5
wtforms==2.2
```

**-- docker-compose.yml --**

```
version: '2'
services:
  form-service:
    build: ./form
    volumes:
      - ./form:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 5001:80
```

**-- Dockerfile --**

```
FROM python:3-onbuild
COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD ["python", "api.py"]
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce; wtforms is installed in the container as expected.  Is `requirements.txt` located inside the `form` directory?  Did you run `docker-compose build` after adding `wtforms` to `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Turns out I forgot to do `docker-compose build`. However, now I have an AttributeError: `type object 'UserForm' has no attribute 'as_view'. I was under the impression that I would be able to view the results within localhost:5001 or do I still need an html template?

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.